# Opening previously saved matlab file

Tags: file, matlab, loading

I'm new to matlab. I am using matlab r2010b. I have saved a .mat file and cannot get it to open in matlab. Is there a function that I must use to view the file? Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Check [load](http://www.mathworks.in/help/matlab/ref/load.html) and [importdata](http://www.mathworks.in/help/matlab/ref/importdata.html). The variables will have the names you stored them as.

Comment: i'm not really interested in any variables or data. i'm just trying to recover the workspace. i'm just trying to view what i saved

Comment: Yes, the above 2 still apply. Check this 
http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_env/save-load-and-delete-workspace-variables.html